# JQuery-UI sortable sort on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Images are loaded from Database.
I would like to sort the image order using JQuery-UI sortable and save the data on form submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            cursor: 'crosshair'
    });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

---

```
<form action="" method="post">
<ul id="sortable" style="width: 524px;">
    <li id="00001" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00001.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00002" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00002.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00003" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00003.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00003" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00004.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>  
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<input name="Submit" value="RE-ORDER" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think these links will help you :) http://davidwalsh.name/demo/drag-drop-sort-save-jquery.php http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-drag-ajax

Answer (score 13):

When you sort each time, update the values to a hidden input field using `update: function(){}` in sortable. Here is my code which updates the hidden input when you sort each time. When form is submitted, the values will sent to server.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="image_order" name="image_order" value="" />
<ul id="sortable" style="width: 524px;">
    <li id="00001" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00001.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00002" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00002.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00003" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00003.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00003" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00004.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>  
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<input name="Submit" value="RE-ORDER" type="submit" />
</form>​


 $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            update: function(event, ui) {
                var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
                $('#image_order').val(order.join(","));
                alert($('#image_order').val());
            }
    });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});​
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/SsTdg/).

Answer (score 4):

here is a basic solution as per my thinking

create a hidden input and store its order into it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            update: function(event, ui) {

      var Order = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray').toString();
      $('#order').val(Order);
 }
    });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>

<form action="" method="post">
<ul id="sortable" style="width: 524px;">
    <li id="00001" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00001.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00002" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00002.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00003" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00003.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>
    <li id="00003" class="ui-state-default"><img src="00004.jpg" width="100" height="90" /></li>  
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<input name="order"  type="hidden" />
<input name="Submit" value="RE-ORDER" type="submit" />
</form>
```

now you can get order from `order` .